# Chain rule for differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I've been given this problem:

$y= \sqrt{7+6x^3}$

Using the chain rule am I right in suggesting that

$$u = 7+6x^3$$
$$y = \sqrt{u}$$

Comment: What is U and u?

Comment: I now see what you mean: Yes that is a correct substitution.

Comment: Yeah.. A correct substitution.

Comment: Great thanks. And so, differentiating these gives

du/dx = 18x^2 

dy/du = root u ^-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways to see it: $$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}u} \frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}18x^2 = \frac{9x^2}{\sqrt{7+6x^3}},$$or calling $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $g(x) = 7+6x^3$, we have that $y(x) = f(g(x))$, so: $$y'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{g(x)}}g'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{7+6x^3}}18x^2 = \frac{9x^2}{\sqrt{7+6x^3}}. $$

Comment: May I ask where the 2 comes from?

Comment: Sure. The derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. You can check that by definition or think of the power rule $(x^{1/2})' = \frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}$.